# useState re-renders but the UI isn't updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm using `useState` on an array of objects whose type is a little bit complicated. `set` function tries to change the value of an object in its state. The component is re-rendered as `useEffect` always runs its functions after the `set` function is called, but the UI still remains the same. I suspect the re-render optimization strategy of React but still don't know why. Here's a sample code (actual code is much more complex)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Socket } from 'socket.io-client'

interface MyInterface {
  id: string
  content: string
  extra1: MyInterface[]
  extra2: {
    key1: { some: string; thing: string }[]
    key2: { some: string; thing: string }[]
  }
}

export default function SomeComponent({socket: Socket}) {
  const [myList, setMyList] = useState<MyInterface[]>([])

  const eventListner = (data: { id: string; content: string }) => {
    console.log('eventListner called', data) // logging well
    setMyList((prev: MyInterface[]) =>
      prev.map((item) =>
        item.id === data.id ? { ...item, content: data.content } : item,
      ),
    )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('myList updated', myList) // logging well
  }, [myList])

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("someEvent", eventListener)
  }, [socket])

  // more code...

  return (
    <div>
      {myList.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          {item.id}: {item.content}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Nothing here that sugests it won't re-render.  Can you create a runnable snippet showing the problem.